# How to start Apache nifi 1.17.0?

Tags: apache-nifi

I've downloaded Apache nifi 1.17.0 and tried to start it by bin/run0nifi.bat, but it didn't work. When I click on it window open and disappear in the same time.
I'm working on windows 11 pro
What should i do?

I tried to start it by console and tried to start 1.19.1 and unfortunately it didn't help

I'm a beginner so I might not have done some obvious things
Thx for help)

Comment: Start `cmd` command shell. Goto into the nifi bin folder and run nifi from cmd. This way you should see the error. I guess you don't have java8 installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things first of all:

- you need to make sure that you have installed JAVA on your machine and set the PATH for the JDK in the Environment Variables (JAVA_HOME).
- If JAVA is configured correctly you need to open CMD and go within the NiFi Folder. From there, you should execute the run-nifi.bat manually and see if anythings gets written in the CMD window.

Besides that, you can go within the logs folder and see if any logs are being generated. Most likely you will find something in the nifi-app.log.